# Is there an event dispatched when a series is added to a chart in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-charts

I want to know when the data has been added to a chart so I can use `localToData()` to draw on the chart.  If I do this immediately after setting the dataProvider the chart has not yet updated, so the the call to localToData will not return the correct values.  Is there an event I can subscribe to so I know the chart has drawn the data in the dataProvider?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [CollectionChanged](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#event:collectionChange) event, so you can listen to it. Also, initial data can be fetched using initialize/creationComplete event in the Chart component.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure that would fire when the collection was assigned to the chart though.

Comment: Sure, it will not. But you can build a setter for a collection for that in your custom chart :) TTT, I don't think that is an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

The [updateComplete](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event:updateComplete) event whilst not strictly for this purpose, does fire after the series `updateDisplayList` method has been called, which is close enough.